# Can a genetic algorithm strategy (chromosome) use memory?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I've been wanting to implement a genetic algorithm that devises a strategy for the parachuting robots problem.

Basically two robots land on random locations of an infinite one dimensional world divided into discrete squares. Each robot leaves a parachute where it lands.

The goal is to write an algorithm that if both robots follow its guaranteed to make them meet.

Possible actions. 
Move left, move right, wait a turn. 
Possible states: standing on a parachute, not standing on a parachute.

From what I understand about encoding strategies as a chromosome I could do something like this.

```
0 move left
1 move right 
3 wait
```

And for states first index would be no parachute and second would be with a parachute so

```
03 - move left if you are not on a parachute and wait if you are.
```

The actual solution to the problem involves strategies like: move left and wait in a loop unless you see a parachute and then stop waiting (to catch up with the other robot) how can strategies like that be encoded as a chromosome? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that a language powerful enough to express solutions will be difficult to use in a genetic algorithm. This isn't obviously a puzzle that can be solved with a genetic algorithm. The actual solution should be something like `target=1;repeat{move to target; target=-2*target}` (where `move to x` means go left or right to position `x` relative to the start point). With the additional rule that the robot should stop if it finds the other robot's parachute. The robots will find each other in O(d) time if they start distance d apart.

Comment: I disagree that genetic algorithms won't solve it! Only if you frame it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a genetic algorithm to solve the problem, I believe your best shot is to use a list of 2-digit ints as chromosome.
each digit would represent an action taken for one of the states. so if we say:

0 means move left

1 means move right

3 means wait

Then 01 would mean

```
if(state == noParachute){
    moveLeft();
}else{
    moveright();
}
```

You could just let the length of the chromosome increase over time to get more complex solutions.

A different aproach would be to use a neural network and train it using NEAT.

Comment: Exactly. The key here is that the meaning of a gene is very flexible. The NEAT approach you suggest is based on that flexibility. In NEAT, chromosomes will encode the structure of an artificial neural network that will determine an action given some inputs.